# How to unify a term's operator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I can unify operands in SWI-Prolog, for example:

```
?- +(X,Y) = 1 + 2.
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

but how to unify an operator?

```
?- Op(X,Y) = 1 + 2.
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

I hope Prolog to return

```
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Op = +.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `functor(1 + 2, Op, Arity).`

Comment: Or `(1 + 2) =.. [Op, X, Y].`

Comment: @false Thanks. But `=..` only works for single-side. I have to ask a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786981/how-to-bi-unify-a-terms-operator-in-prolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unify terms. Both `+(1,2)` and `1 + 2` are the same term.
You may use the univ predicate (`=..`) to decompose a term like this:

```
?- 1+2 =.. [Op, X, Y].
Op =  (+),
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

Comment: Can't the LHS of `=..` be a variable? Anyway, I accept this answer and create a new question. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786981/how-to-bi-unify-a-terms-operator-in-prolog

Comment: You can use a variable on the left hand side provided that the right hand side has the first argument of the list bound to an atom. That is, if the left hand side is a variable then the principal functor of the term has to be known.