# How to bi-unify a term's operator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I just asked the question in [How to unify a term's operator in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785719/how-to-unify-a-terms-operator-in-prolog) and got good answers.

However, it doesn't completely solve my problem, i.e. `=..` only works for single-side.

For example,

```
test(Expr) :-
  1 + 2 = Expr.
test(Expr) :-
  1 * 2 = Expr.

?- E =.. [Op, X, Y], test(E). % E can not be a variable!
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I hope the query returns

```
Op = (+),
X = 1,
Y = 2;
Op = (*),
X = 1,
Y = 2.
```

Very thanks.

Comment: You have a syntax error. It's `=..` and not `..=`. You can use a variable on the left hand side provided that the right hand side has the first argument of the list bound to an atom.

Comment: So in your sample code you could for example select Op from a list of possible operators. Something like this: `member(Op, [(+), (*)]), E =.. [Op, X, Y], test(E).`

Comment: @gusbro. oops. It should be `=..` sorry. I changed the query to `?- E =.. [Op, X, Y], test(E).`, prolog complains `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. I edited question for this syntax error.

Comment: @gusbro `member(Op, [(+), (*)])` seems a good way. Thanks.

Comment: Just a minor point: You can always write `[+,*]` in place of `[(+),(*)]`. No need for these extra round brackets within lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr_op_x_y(Expr, Op, X, Y) :-
   when((nonvar(Expr) ; nonvar(Op)), Expr =.. [Op, X, Y]).

?- expr_op_x_y(Expr, Op, X, Y).
   when((nonvar(Expr);nonvar(Op)),Expr=..[Op,X,Y]).
?- expr_op_x_y(Expr, Op, X, Y), Op = (+).
   Expr = X+Y, Op = (+).
?- expr_op_x_y(Expr, Op, X, Y), Expr = 1+2.
   Expr = 1+2, Op = (+), X = 1, Y = 2.
```

This could also be called a boomy univ for entirely historical reasons.